# laravel route loading non existing route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

Please am stuck here. i have a laravel project when i access the ROOT route `'/'` it keeps redirecting to `'/home'` even when the route: `'/home'` is not declared. i have cleared the route cache and also check if the `redirectIfAuthenticated.php` HOME route is to `'/'` on purpose but to no avail. i want assign a controller to the root route

Project is based on `laravel 7.x`. below is my `route/web.php` file:

```
/* Authentication Routes */

Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
Route::get('email/verify', 'Auth\VerificationController@show')->name('verification.notice');
Route::get('email/verify/{id}/{hash}', 'Auth\VerificationController@verify')->name('verification.verify');
Route::post('email/resend', 'Auth\VerificationController@resend')->name('verification.resend');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
Route::get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
Route::get('password/confirm', 'Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@showConfirmForm')->name('password.confirm');
Route::post('password/confirm', 'Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@confirm');
Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset')->name('password.update');


Route::group(['prefix' => 'user', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
  Route::get('/product', 'ProductController@index')->name('user_list_product');
  Route::get('/profile/edit', 'HomeController@edit')->name('edit_profile');
  Route::get('/product/create', 'ProductController@create')->name('user_create_product');
  Route::get('/product/edit/{product_id}', 'ProductController@edit')->name('user_edit_product');
});

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@homepage')->name('homepage');
Route::get('/product/view/{product_id}', 'ProductController@show')->name('view_product');
```

output of `php artisan route:list`

```
+--------+----------+------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                                      | Name                              | Action                                                                    | Middleware   |
+--------+----------+------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /                                        | homepage                          | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@homepage                              | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/category/list                        |                                   | App\Http\Controllers\API\CategoryController@index                         | api          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/city/find/{findable}/in/{state_code} | api_find_city_in_state            | App\Http\Controllers\API\CityController@find_city_in_state                | api          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/city/list                            |                                   | App\Http\Controllers\API\CityController@index                             | api          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/city/list_for/{state_code}           | api_list_city_for_state_code      | App\Http\Controllers\API\CityController@list_city_for_state_code          | api          |
|        | POST     | api/login                                | api_login                         | App\Http\Controllers\API\AuthController@login                             | api          |
|        | POST     | api/product/find                         |                                   | App\Http\Controllers\API\ProductController@find                           | api          |
|        | POST     | api/product/list                         | api_list_product                  | App\Http\Controllers\API\ProductController@index                          | api          |
|        | POST     | api/register                             | api_register                      | App\Http\Controllers\API\AuthController@store                             | api          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/state/find/{findable}                | api_find_state                    | App\Http\Controllers\API\StateController@find_state                       | api          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/state/list                           |                                   | App\Http\Controllers\API\StateController@index                            | api          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/subcategory/list                     |                                   | App\Http\Controllers\API\CategoryController@index                         | api          |
|        | POST     | api/update                               | api_update                        | App\Http\Controllers\API\AuthController@update                            | api          |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | auth:api     |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user/list                            |                                   | App\Http\Controllers\API\AuthController@index                             | api          |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | auth:api     |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user/product/delete/{product_id}     |                                   | App\Http\Controllers\API\ProductController@destroy                        | api          |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | auth:api     |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user/product/disable/{product_id}    |                                   | App\Http\Controllers\API\ProductController@disable                        | api          |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | auth:api     |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user/product/find/{findable}         |                                   | App\Http\Controllers\API\ProductController@find                           | api          |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | auth:api     |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user/product/like/{product_id}       |                                   | App\Http\Controllers\API\ProductController@like                           | api          |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | auth:api     |
|        | POST     | api/user/product/list                    | api_user_list_product             | App\Http\Controllers\API\ProductController@user_index                     | api          |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | auth:api     |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user/product/report/{product_id}     |                                   | App\Http\Controllers\API\ProductController@report                         | api          |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | auth:api     |
|        | POST     | api/user/product/save                    | api_save_new_product              | App\Http\Controllers\API\ProductController@store                          | api          |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | auth:api     |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user/product/unlike/{product_id}     |                                   | App\Http\Controllers\API\ProductController@unlike                         | api          |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | auth:api     |
|        | POST     | api/user/product/update/{product_id}     | api_update_product                | App\Http\Controllers\API\ProductController@update                         | api          |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | auth:api     |
|        | POST     | email/resend                             | verification.resend               | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\VerificationController@resend                   | web          |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | auth         |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | throttle:6,1 |
|        | GET|HEAD | email/verify                             | verification.notice               | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\VerificationController@show                     | web          |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | auth         |
|        | GET|HEAD | email/verify/{id}/{hash}                 | verification.verify               | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\VerificationController@verify                   | web          |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | auth         |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | signed       |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | throttle:6,1 |
|        | GET|HEAD | login                                    | login                             | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                   | web          |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | guest        |
|        | POST     | login                                    |                                   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                           | web          |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | guest        |
|        | POST     | logout                                   | logout                            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                          | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | oauth/authorize                          | passport.authorizations.authorize | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AuthorizationController@authorize       | web          |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | auth         |
|        | DELETE   | oauth/authorize                          | passport.authorizations.deny      | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\DenyAuthorizationController@deny        | web          |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | auth         |
|        | POST     | oauth/authorize                          | passport.authorizations.approve   | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ApproveAuthorizationController@approve  | web          |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | auth         |
|        | POST     | oauth/clients                            | passport.clients.store            | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ClientController@store                  | web          |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | auth         |
|        | GET|HEAD | oauth/clients                            | passport.clients.index            | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ClientController@forUser                | web          |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | auth         |
|        | DELETE   | oauth/clients/{client_id}                | passport.clients.destroy          | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ClientController@destroy                | web          |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | auth         |
|        | PUT      | oauth/clients/{client_id}                | passport.clients.update           | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ClientController@update                 | web          |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | auth         |
|        | POST     | oauth/personal-access-tokens             | passport.personal.tokens.store    | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\PersonalAccessTokenController@store     | web          |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | auth         |
|        | GET|HEAD | oauth/personal-access-tokens             | passport.personal.tokens.index    | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\PersonalAccessTokenController@forUser   | web          |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | auth         |
|        | DELETE   | oauth/personal-access-tokens/{token_id}  | passport.personal.tokens.destroy  | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\PersonalAccessTokenController@destroy   | web          |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | auth         |
|        | GET|HEAD | oauth/scopes                             | passport.scopes.index             | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ScopeController@all                     | web          |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | auth         |
|        | POST     | oauth/token                              | passport.token                    | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController@issueToken        | throttle     |
|        | POST     | oauth/token/refresh                      | passport.token.refresh            | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\TransientTokenController@refresh        | web          |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | auth         |
|        | GET|HEAD | oauth/tokens                             | passport.tokens.index             | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AuthorizedAccessTokenController@forUser | web          |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | auth         |
|        | DELETE   | oauth/tokens/{token_id}                  | passport.tokens.destroy           | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AuthorizedAccessTokenController@destroy | web          |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | auth         |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/confirm                         | password.confirm                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@showConfirmForm       | web          |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | auth         |
|        | POST     | password/confirm                         |                                   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@confirm               | web          |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | auth         |
|        | POST     | password/email                           | password.email                    | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail     | web          |
|        | POST     | password/reset                           | password.update                   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                   | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset                           | password.request                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm    | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset/{token}                   | password.reset                    | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm           | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | product/view/{product_id}                | view_product                      | App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@show                               | web          |
|        | POST     | register                                 |                                   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                     | web          |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | guest        |
|        | GET|HEAD | register                                 | register                          | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm         | web          |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | guest        |
|        | GET|HEAD | user/product                             | user_list_product                 | App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@index                              | web          |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | auth         |
|        | GET|HEAD | user/product/create                      | user_create_product               | App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@create                             | web          |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | auth         |
|        | GET|HEAD | user/product/edit/{product_id}           | user_edit_product                 | App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@edit                               | web          |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | auth         |
|        | GET|HEAD | user/profile/edit                        | edit_profile                      | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@edit                                  | web          |
|        |          |                                          |                                   |                                                                           | auth         |
+--------+----------+------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: `php artisan route:clear` then see all routes by `php artisan route:list`

Comment: @STA i did that, updated my question with the output

Comment: May be you got this because `HomeController@homepage` point to `/home`  what do you get at `/home`?

Comment: i have a blank page after it automatically redirects to `'\home'`  because no `'\home'` route
this is the HomeController@homepage action:
`public function hompage()
  {
    return view('homepage');
  }`

Comment: You go to /home after login, right?

Comment: @STA no not from login.  like if i type into my browser:  `localhost:8000` it redirects to `localhost:8000/home`

Comment: `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php` also poined to */home*, but I am not sure this can solve your issue or not `protected $redirectTo = '/home';` and `return redirect()->route('home');` you can make a try

Answer (score 0):

From this directory `app/providers`, open `RouteServicePorvider.php` file and edit as follow

```php
    /**
     * The path to the "home" route for your application.
     *
     * @var string
     */

    public const HOME = '/home';
```

**Change to**

```php
    public const HOME = '/';
```